# The probability that the absolute value of the difference between the numbers is greater than one

Tags: probability

Pick 2 numbers : one from interval [0,1] and second one from interval [0,2]. Calculate the probability that the absolute value of the difference between the numbers is greater than one.

---

I defined 2 numbers : $x \in [0,1]$ $y\in[0,2]$. I've been thinking on this problem and came up with a few ideas, but sketching a graph and calculating the field is the easiest (I think). I used the definition of an absolute value and got $x-y>1 \equiv  y<x-1 $ - doesn't work since $y\in[0,2]$. $x-y<-1 \equiv y>x+1$. I drew a simple sketch and calculated the area : $1\cdot1\cdot\cfrac{1}{2} = \cfrac{1}{2}$. Is it correct? If it is, how to solve this task without drawing anything, this is using integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is okay and the area of $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,2]\mid |x-y|>1\}$ is indeed $\frac12$.

But in order to find the probability you must divide this by the area of $[0,1]\times[0,2]$ which is $2$.

So the probability equals $\frac14$.

---

If you want to avoid pictures you can go for finding:$$P\left(\left|X-Y\right|>1\right)=\int_{0}^{1}P\left(\left|X-Y\right|>1\mid X=x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}P\left(\left|x-Y\right|>1\mid X=x\right)dx$$$$=\int_{0}^{1}P\left(\left|x-Y\right|>1\right)dx$$where the last equality rests on independence.

Here $Y$ has uniform distribution on $[0,2]$ so that:$$P(|x-Y|>1)=P(Y>1+x)=\frac12(1-x)$$

Comment: Why do we need to divide by area?

Comment: In short: to make it a probability. Suppose that we have sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ with $A\subseteq B$ and $X$ has uniform distribution on $B$. If $a$ is the area of $A$ and $b$ is the area of $B$ then $P(X\in B)=\frac{b}{b}=1$ and $P(X\in A)=\frac{a}{b}$. Areas on their own are not probabilities yet (they can exceed $1$) but must be standardized.

Comment: What if I had to calculate $|x-y| \geq 1$. Would the answer be the same?

Comment: Yes. Because the set $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,2]\mid|x-y|=1\}$ has probability $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independently and uniformly chosen from these intervals $P(|X-Y| >1)=P(Y>X+1)=\frac  1 2 E[2-(X+1)]=\frac 12 (1-\frac 1  2)=\frac 1  4$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very mathematical solution, but computer simulation verifies 0.25 probability (250 million out of 1 billion).  It is a good way to help verify mathematical solutions and an even better way to help verify difficult counting problems.

Comment: This problem somewhat reminds me of a similar one which is given a unit square, what the the average distance between 2 random points inside that square.  I suppose in this case it could be a 1 x 2 rectangle instead of a square.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that the probability is $1/4$ is to turn the random choice of $y\in[0,2]$ into $y=1+\sigma u$, where $\sigma\in\{1,-1\}$ and $u\in[0,1]$. In order for $|y-x|\gt1$, we must have $\sigma=1$, which occurs with probability $1/2$, and $u\gt x$, which, by symmetry (since $x$ and $u$ are both chosen from $[0,1]$), also occurs with probability $1/2$.